# How to get the text of an element inside a link with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I need a simple script that I can enter an url in and it can get me the text of a certain html element in the page. 
For example: 
Inside https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query=Daley+Blind&x=0&y=0
I need to have the "Position" which is CB in this case and have it console logged in my page for example.

Thank you

Comment: Hire someone :)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat :D

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take this url as a string and then use the split method for string to split it accordingly.

If the url is always similar i.e. the format is always same then you can do some thing like this.

```
s="https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query=Daley+Blind&x=0&y=0"

s=s.strip("&")
x=s[-2]
y=s[-1]

x=x.split("=")
y=y.split("=")

xCord=x[-1]
yCord=y[-1]
```

If you want an html element form the page. You can do something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="Your url"
source=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")

# the div block of element id or even class
element=soup.find('div',id='your id')


print(element)
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves your problem or do let me know.

Comment: and how do I get the value of the html element inside the link?

Comment: I am not getting exactly what you want. Do you want to get something from the url link or the from the webpage of this link.I suggest you to explain little more as the question is not clear. Suggest you for an edit.

Comment: In case you want to get some thing from the page as some html elements the it is called web scrapping. You can use beautifulsoup and request module for the same.